# WP_Query don't show pagination for frontpage

Tags: wordpress, post

Can someone take a look on my code ? I can't figure why post pagination not showing, although when I type page/2 in browser url, the list of post works properly.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Frontpage
 *
 * @package Bootstrap Canvas WP
 * @since Bootstrap Canvas WP 1.0
 */

    get_header(); ?>

<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'orderby' => 'ASC', 'paged'  => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 9 );
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
$count = 0;

?>

      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 blog-main pt-3 pb-5">

        <?php if ($loop->have_posts()) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $count++ ?>
        <?php  $date_format = get_option( 'date_format' ); ?>
        <?php if($count == 1) : ?>
         <div class="row">
         <?php endif ?>
         <?php if(($count == 1) || ($count == 9)) : ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-xl-8 np-big">
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php if($count == 2 || $count == 7) : ?>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4 np-small">
        <?php endif ?>
             <?php if($count > 1 && $count < 4 || $count > 6 && $count <= 9 ) : ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">
            <?php elseif ($count >= 4) : ?>
            <?php if ($count == 5) : ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4  np-small">
            <?php else : ?>
            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4">
                <?php endif ?>
            <?php endif ?>
              <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="post-bg-home" style="background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) ), url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>);">
            <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
            <p class="data"><?php  echo the_time( $date_format ); ?></p>
                </div></a>
        <?php if($count == 1) : ?>
        </div>


        <?php endif ?>
               <?php if($count > 1 ) : ?>
        </div>
<?php endif ?>
     <?php if($count == 3 || $count == 8) : ?>
      </div>
      <?php endif ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        </div>



             <div class="paginacja col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">
                 <hr class="paginacja-hr">
                 <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
             </div>



        <?php else : ?>

        <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <h1>Not Found</h1>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>


    </div><!-- /.blog-main -->

      </div><!-- /.row -->

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'orderby' => 'ASC', 'paged'  => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 3 );
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
$count = 0;

?>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 blog-main pt-3 pb-5">

            <?php if ($loop->have_posts()) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $count++ ?>
            <?php  $date_format = get_option( 'date_format' ); ?>
                <?php if($count == 1) : ?>
                 <div class="row">
                 <?php endif ?>
                 <?php if(($count == 1) || ($count == 9)) : ?>
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-xl-8 np-big">
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if($count == 2 || $count == 7) : ?>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4 np-small">
                <?php endif ?>
                         <?php if($count > 1 && $count < 4 || $count > 6 && $count <= 9 ) : ?>
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">
                    <?php elseif ($count >= 4) : ?>
                    <?php if ($count == 5) : ?>
                    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4  np-small">
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-xl-4">
                            <?php endif ?>
                    <?php endif ?>
                          <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>"><div class="post-bg-home" style="background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) ), url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>);">
                        <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
                        <p class="data"><?php  echo the_time( $date_format ); ?></p>
                                </div></a>
                <?php if($count == 1) : ?>
                </div>


                <?php endif ?>
                           <?php if($count > 1 ) : ?>
                </div>
<?php endif ?>
         <?php if($count == 3 || $count == 8) : ?>
          </div>
          <?php endif ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
                </div>



                         <div class="paginacja col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">
                             <hr class="paginacja-hr">
                             <?php $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;
                the_posts_pagination( array(
                   'mid_size' => 1,
                   'prev_text' => __( 'Back', 'green' ),
                   'next_text' => __( 'Next', 'green' ),
                   'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Posts navigation' )
                ) );  ?>
                         </div>



            <?php else : ?>

                <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                    <h1>Not Found</h1>
                </div>

            <?php endif; ?>


        </div><!-- /.blog-main -->

      </div><!-- /.row -->

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```